# MUI v5 Popper scroll playground replicate in code sandbox

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Where can I find the reference code for MUI v5 Popper scroll playground? I am having difficulties with the dynamic arrow in popper.

Arrow is not dynamic.

https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-5-forked-pd5wmk

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-popper/#scroll-playground

[image]

This one to be exact.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed. You can check out the fixed version in following link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-5-forked-pd5wmk?file=/src/ArrowPopper.tsx